# How to open all nodes and objects in window/console when inspect element?

Tags: browser, firebug, opera, development-environment, google-chrome-devtools

1) I need to open all nodes at once in Google Chrome Developer (devtools). For example, on the pictures you can see `<body>` and `<div id="mngb">` opened, but `<head>` not
https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/images/Desktop2.png

2) More over, i need to open all objects in console. For example, when i type console.log(object);
Here is a problem: when i press Search in console, it **makes search only via opened objects**.

By the way, i noticed such a problem in other browsers (Opera, Firebug).

thank you

Comment: What if there's a circular reference? You can't expand that.

Comment: `var a={}; a.a=a; console.log(a)`

Comment: You could search inside `element.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera Dragonfly has a button which expands the entire DOM tree, but I can't find any such function in Chrome.

You can use `console.dir(obj)` to display an object expanded in Opera Dragonfly, but it will only expand the first level. Chrome doesn't expand objects when you use this function though.